# How to create nested >:not() statements?

Tags: html, css

I have code that looks like this as of now

```
body > :not(form) {
    display:none !important;
}
```

I am trying to display only the elements found in 'form' tag for a print screen. However, now I realize that the form tag contains undesirable div tags with id's such as

```
<div id="logo">
<div id= "tabs">
<div id="topbar">
```

Only the `<div id="body">` is desirable. I have tried doing

```
body > :not(form) > :not(#body) {
    display:none !important;
}
```

and

```
body > :not(form) > :not(#logo) > :not(tabs) > :not(topbar) {
    display: none !important;
    form > :not(#body) {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get only the #body element to show within the #form element? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kevin, please post the HTML snippet of interest so as to facilitate those who might want to try to help you out.  Thank!

Comment: just looking at this I can tell you I've never come across code like this. most likely you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `body > :not(form) > :not(#body)` will not work because as you described, `#body` element is *within* form, while previous part of the rule explicitly states that you want to search under *non-form* elements.

In your case combination of two rules should work properly:

```
body > :not(form),
body > * > :not(#body) {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Check the test demo (everything should be hidden except BODY in form tag):

```css
body >:not(form),
body > * > :not(#body) {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>DIV</div>
<form>
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div id="body">BODY</div>
    <div id="topbar">TOPBAR</div>
</form>
<p>P</p>
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track. Can you explain why your second line has an asterik?

Comment: Going one step further, what if there is another div id = "subbody" nested in the "body" div and i just want to show the "subbody" div?? If you can show me that that would be amazing.

Comment: Similarly, you would add `body > * > * > :not(#subbody)` part: http://jsfiddle.net/8ads3nya/

Comment: I added that statment, but it still shows both the "body" div and the "subbody" div. Any idea why?

Comment: `body` will be shown of course because you need to show it's child. You can't hide parent and show its child at the same time. So `body` children should be put in separate divs, but only `subbody` will stay visible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach.

```
form > div {
    display: none;
}
form > div#body {
    display: block;
}
```

The first rule hides every child `div` within all the `form` elements.

The second rule enables the `div#body` to be displayed (hence, printable).

If you have more than one form, you may need to make the selectors more specific.

You don't actually need the `:not` (negation) pseudo-class.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Answer (score 0):

Give your desired elements a class of:

```
.printme
```

Everything else:

```
.donotprintme
```

Then this:

```
@media print
{
    .printme { display:block; }
    .donotprintme { display: none; }
}
```